# RStudio button "Run tests" for testthat changes to user directory ('~')

Tags: rstudio, testthat

Testthat is working fine when testing the package via 'devtools::test()', but not when testing interactive via the "Run Tests" button within RStudio. The issue is caused by the working directory when loading a config file.

"Run tests" loads the package in a clean environment with the user directory ('~') as working directory. My project is setup to use the project directory as working directory, but this is ignored.

How to setup RStudio correctly to use the project directory as working directory for interactive testing?